# Como modificar, apenas via CSS, uma cor já definida no HTML?

Tags: css3, layout

Estou tentando modificar uma cor em um texto, marcado que a pela tag "U" com a cor já definida no html.

está assim no html:

```html
<u> <font color="#0000c0">somente no seu e-commerce</font> </u>
```

Tentei da seguinte maneira no CSS:

```
u{ color:rgb(20,20,20) !important; }
```

Porém não aceita a cor, creio que pelo fato de está definida no código fonte.

O detalhe importante, eu não tenho acesso a modificar o HTML, pois é gerado por software web. Toda modificação de layout tem q ser feita apenas por CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente `u > font { color: corDesejada !important; }`

Comment: Excelente! deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: Disponha. Harry Carvalho